# unable to use python module inside a brownie script: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, solidity

Brownie framework community:

please help. I'm trying to use an external python module, PyGithub, in my python script in the scripts folder. I've pip installed it:

```
pip install PyGithub
```

In scripts/create.py, I try to import it:

```
from github import Github  <----- error

from brownie import accounts, convert

def main(): ...
```

however, when I try running it:

```
brownie run create.py
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'
```

The import statement works perfectly fine in python. Any suggestions on how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: HI, Did u check https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/856, the thread is very long with many people reporting this issue with few resolutions, you can try. Just upvote if any of those solutions worked for you.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip freeze | less` can you tell me what version of github you see?

Comment: @PatrickCollins  PyGithub==1.55

Comment: thanks for the link @Venkat. unfortunately, that didn't resolve my issue

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue. Can you make this an issue on the `brownie` repo here: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie